# What is a word to describe these two separate but related items in a software application?

Tags: single-word-requests

Some background: I am working on the menu for an online homework assignment generator.  In this program, the user will click through a series of pages and fill in necessary information (assigned & due dates, questions included, order & number of questions, etc).  At the top of each page is a group of tabs to allow the user to switch between the pages.

The current tabs have the labels:

- Details
- Questions
- Edit
- Print
- Done

All pretty self-explanatory.

Now, a page is being added to the application in which the user can make the assignment only be assigned to certain students in the class, or give certain students different assigned or due dates.

The question is: what would be a good tab label for this page?  I'm looking for a single word that would describe to the user what they can do on this page.  Two words could possibly fit in the tab, but no more than that.

Comment: Would "Custom" or "Custom Assignments" work?

Comment: I don't think 'Custom' would work, but 'Customize' might.  Thankee.

Comment: “Exceptions” (or “Create Exceptions” or “Identify Exceptions”, etc.)? “Fine-Tuning”?  “Special Cases”?

Comment: Umm, what ‘‘two separate but related items’’ are you referring to?

Comment: You've used the word _assiged_ in your question to describe the linking of a piece of homework to a group of students. How about _Assign_ as your tab label?

Comment: ........Tailor.

Comment: @Scott: I was referring to making certain assignments only be for certain people, and making certain people get different due dates for assignments.  The 'related' bit is that, in both cases, certain students are being treated differently from the rest of the class as regards particular assignments, but they are separate because they are different kinds of special treatment, if that makes sense.

Comment: Call the tab: ***Assign***

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because our Help Center says choosing names for programming is off-topic here.

Comment: The item in the help center says "programming variables / classes", which are internal to the program and only seen by the developer(s).  This was looking for a word to be read by the user, which I would think falls squarely under "word choice and usage".

Answer (score 0):

If it is an assignment for just certain students, I suggest a name "Special Assignment" or "Personal Assignment" (or plural, if more than one), and show it ONLY if current student does have such assignment (hide button if no such assignments). If you have to show it always, show the number (which would be 0 if none are assigned), like: "Personal Assignment (0)".

Number is to improve usability: if such bonus assignments are rare, it is frustrating to open something just to see nothing it there, and after a while you will train your users never open it - which is exactly the opposite you want.

If you need to save the space, just "Personal (0)" is OK too.

If your font does not distinguish between uppercase O and 0 (zero), "None" is better than confusing 0.

If such assignment is for extra points, you can use "Bonus (2)".

If all students have same assignment, but due on different dates (why would you even consider that? What would be a business reason to do that), just show due date with the assignment, no need of special page.

Answer (score 0):

Permissions, Roles, Groups, Advanced (where you can house all additional functionalities in the future as well)